# Append Two String to LCD Using MikroC and Proteus

Tags: pic

I tried to read EEPROM values and display that value with a string.

This is my MikroC code:

```
char shed;
char shedn[]= "S";
char shedfn;
unsigned shedno;

void main(){
  shedno =  EEPROM_Read(0x00);
  shedno = 256 - shedno;
  delay_ms(50);
  WordToStr(shedno, shed);
  strcpy(shedfn, shedn);
  strcat(shedfn, shed);
  Lcd_Out(1,1,shedfn);
}
```

All LCD code has in my code and not mention here and it is working fine.

I am using pic16f887 microcontroller and that give following error in proteus.

```
[PIC16 CORE] PC=0x019E. Indirect write of 0x53 to address 0x0080 is itself an indirect write. [U1]

[PIC16 CORE] PC=0x0183. Indirect write of 0x00 to address 0x0080 is itself an indirect write. [U1]
```

Comment: Maybe you should allocate for "shed" and "shedfn" first. I'm not sure but the warnings/errors can be due to overlapping.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been abandoned by the asker for years, was originally a pure programming problem, and the error has long since been explained should the asker care to re-visit and notice.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
strcpy(shedfn, shedn);
```

shouldn't be able to compile since shedfn is a char and not a char array or a pointer. Isn't there an error, or at least a warning, from the compiler?